# How to capture GET/POST request made from MFC web browser c++

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, mfc, atl

I have MFC application which is basically web browser. I have used CHTMLView class for that. On executing app, it will navigate to some default web page. On that page there are some buttons. On clicking any button will generate GET/POST requests. I want to capture those GET/POST request and its responses. Also I have to make sure that responses that browser is getting is from valid source.

Following webpage is similar to the page I am working on [support.google.com/books/partner/answer/3254227?hl=en](http://support.google.com/books/partner/answer/3254227?hl=en) On this web page there is 'Yes' & 'No' button. On clicking on any of those buttons, it sends some POST/GET request

Comment: You could use Igor Tandetnik's Passthrough App: https://blog.salsitasoft.com/igor-tandetniks-passthrough-app-now-on-github/

Comment: How are these POST/GET requests being sent?  Form? XMLHttpRequest?  Some other way?

Comment: My MFC application don't have control over how those request being sent. Button is on the web page and that have some java script associated with it and onClick event it is sending those requests

Comment: You should show MCVE, instead of describing the website in one sentence. `CHTMLView` doesn't have a problem with buttons and Javascript. See if it works on Internet Explorer

Comment: @Barmak - Following webpage is similar to the page I am working on 
[https://support.google.com/books/partner/answer/3254227?hl=en][1]   On this web page there is 'Yes' & 'No' button. On clicking on any of those buttons, it sends some POST/GET request

Comment: The above page works fine with my own `CHtmlView` class, on Windows 10, VS 2017. Google's main search page also has a button, lots of web pages have buttons and javascript. IE is not compatible with some new websites, but if it works on IE it should work in browser control.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani - Did you get call to 'OnBeforeNavigate2' or 'OnNavigateComplete2' methods when you click on "YES" or "NO" button of that page ? When page loads at that time those methods gets called but on clicking those 'yes' and 'no' button, none of the chtmlView methods are invoked.

Comment: No, I don't get `OnNavigate...` messages for those. The page doesn't appear to reload. This could be Ajax or iframe etc.

Answer (score 2):

`CHTMLViewer` wraps an [`IWebBrowser2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/shdocvw.iwebbrowser2?view=dynamics-usd-30). The useful parts are wrapped. In this case, you want the `CHtmlView::OnBeforeNavigate2` callback. It's called with the GET or POST request.

If you don't trust the URL (i.e. not a valid source), you can use the last `cancel` parameter in `OnBeforeNavigate2` to stop the GET or POST.

Comment: Thanks @MSalters, In my case when I click button on the webpage, it doesn't navigate to other page, instead of that it just sends GET or POST request. As click event does not cause navigation to other page, "OnBeforeNavigate2" method never invoked